# Reshaping a distribution

Tags: normal-distribution, normalization

Not sure what the exact term is for what I'm trying to do.

I have a data set with random variable x with values X1, X2, ..., XN that has a standard deviation sigma and a mean m.

I want to perturb the values of X1, X2, ..., XN so that the new distribution has a standard deviation of sigma' and mean m'.

I would like an algorithm (or an implementation in Java) that does that.

Thanks.

Comment: Without more information, there are too many possible answers, because your formulation allows us to replace your data with literally *any* set of $N$ values having the desired mean and SD. Please either provide enough information to answer this question or consider telling us *why* you want to undertake this exercise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you know $m$ and $\sigma$ and your random variable is $X$, then let $Z = m^ \prime + {\frac {\sigma^\prime} \sigma}(X - m)$. It's called an affine transformation, although you'll probably see it more often called a linear transformation. Technically it's a linear transformation followed by a translation (according to Wikipedia).

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I wanted to do - what is this procedure I'm trying to accomplish called?

Comment: $Y = m^ \prime - {\frac {\sigma^\prime} \sigma}(X - m)$, i.e. $Y = 2m^ \prime - Z$, has the same mean and standard deviation

Comment: I've heard some call it "normalizing" the data, but that is not an accurate term. You're scaling the variance and shifting the mean.